# Is the Euler-Cromer method? Or is it incorrect?

Tags: python, physics, numerical-methods

```
k=3;m=123
eulerC_x=[A]
eulerC_v=[0]
eulerC_t=[0]
c=0
for z in np.arange(t_euler,t_max,dt_euler):
    a=-(k/m)*eulerC_x[c]
    eulerC_v.append(eulerC_v[c]+a*dt_euler)
    eulerC_x.append(eulerC_x[c]+eulerC_v[c+1]*dt_euler) 
    #c+1 uses new velocity value to update the position, removing the energy increase in euler         
    eulerC_t.append(z)
    c+=1
```

This is code solving an ODE related to simple harmonic motion.
My lecturer seems to think that this is wrong as I am updating the velocity first, then using the (n+1) velocity to calculate the new position. He thinks I should update the position first, then use the (n+1) position to calculate the new velocity. Every resource line is saying what I think is right but my lecturer is saying the opposite.
This removes the energy increase in my Euler method, and my graphs confirm this. I just want to know if its right. Thanks!

Comment: instead of `[c+1]` you can also use the index of the last element `[-1]`.  Then you do not need `c`. The whole is one variant of the symplectic Euler method.

Answer (score 0):

This [semi-explicit Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) is indeed symplectic and also carries the name Euler-Cromer.

It is a first-order method. As symplectic method this means that there is a first-order modification of the energy function that is constant, or at least changes at a higher order. In this case where the energy is quadratic in position and impulse the modified energy is indeed constant up to floating-point error accumulation. The physical energy without the modification will oscillate in a constant band of width O(h), where h is the step size.

There are two variants of the semi-implicit symplectic Euler method, both are correct. You implemented one, your teacher refers to the other. As they have opposite local truncation errors, combining them alternatingly cancels the first-order error terms, one gets a second-order symplectic method, the Verlet method.